# Nested JSON to Java Mapping with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json structure like this:

```
   [
       {
        "param1": "one",
        "param2": "two",
        "nestedStruct1": {
            "param1": "one",
            "param2": "two",
            "param3": "three"
        },
    }
]
```

We use Jackson for performing the json-to-java object processing. I am not certain how to create the corresponding java class that would support this nested json construct.

Is it sufficient to create two separate classes along the lines of the following:

```
public class Outside {
    private String param1 = null;
    private String param2 = null;
    private Inside inside = new Inside();

    // appropriate getters and setters  
}

public class Inside {
    private String param1 = null;
    private String param2 = null;
    private String param3 = null;

    // appropriate getters and setters
}
```

Any insights are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the code that you provided? You also may want to look into the @JsonProperty annotation.

Comment: Your Json starts with an array. are you expecting multiple outside object in your json array?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a JSON array (well, it is not correctly formatted) and one single element of it can be (de)serialized from/to the following class structure directly by the `ObjectMapper`. We use such an embedded structure all the times. Elements must be public (or have corresponding getters/setters) or, if I am not mistaken, at least protected. Note that the field name for your embedded structure needs to correspond to that in JSON:

```
public class Element {
  public String param1;
  public String param2;
  public Embedded nestedStruct1 = new Embedded();

  public static class Embedded {
    public String param1;
    public String param2;
    public String param3;
  } 
}
```

The whole array can be (de)serialized from/to a list `List<Element>`.